# terraform import fails with terraform cloud remote backend

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-github, terraform-cloud

I'm trying to import an existing github repository to terraform. I decided to try terraform cloud, and after setting that up, `terraform import`s fail with `401 unauthorized`, even if everything is set up properly.

Basically, I have this:

```
provider "github" {
  token        = "${var.github_token}"
  organization = "goreleaser"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.12.0"
}

variable "github_token" {
  type = string
}

resource "github_repository" "goreleaser" {
  name = "goreleaser"
}
```

If I run `terraform import github_repository.goreleaser goreleaser`, it works as expected (I have a `TF_VAR_github_token` on the environment).

If I add the remote backend:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.12.0"

  backend "remote" {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "goreleaser"

    workspaces {
      name = "tf"
    }
  }
}
```

And run the same command, I get:

```
github_repository.goreleaser: Importing from ID "goreleaser"...
github_repository.goreleaser: Import prepared!
  Prepared github_repository for import
github_repository.goreleaser: Refreshing state... [id=goreleaser]

Error: GET https://api.github.com/repos/goreleaser/goreleaser: 401 Bad credentials []
```

Should this work?

I have the variable set up on terraform cloud as well - remote `terraform plan` works, but import is failing.

Comment: How are you providing your Terraform cloud token?

Comment: on `~/.terraformrc`, as per documentation...

Comment: `terraform import` is currently (as of Terraform 0.12.9) a local-only command, which will run on the system where you are running `terraform import` even if the workspace is configured for remote operations. Therefore for _import_ you'll need to have your GitHub API credentials configured locally. Remote operations only supports the main `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` workflow commands.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I have it locally as well, as an environment variable (`TF_VAR_github_token`). Do I need to set it up differently?

Comment: Did you try setting the credentials on the Terraform Cloud workspace? I think the `terraform import` is executed on Terraform Cloud, similar to how a `terraform plan` is executed on Terraform Cloud when using the remote backend